# How Can Calculate Entropy of hexvalue extracted from file?

Tags: c#, hex, entropy

i used this code to calculate entropy of hex value

```
public static double ShannonEntropy(string s)
{
    string[] hexValuesSplit = s.Split(' ');

    var map = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    foreach (String hex in hexValuesSplit)
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);

        if (!map.ContainsKey(value))
            map.Add(value, 1);
        else
            map[value] += 1;

    }

    double result = 0.0;
    int len = s.Length;
    foreach (var item in map)
    {
        var frequency = (double)item.Value / len;
        result -= frequency * (Math.Log(frequency) / Math.Log(2));
    }

    return result;
}
```

the hex value something like this "4D 5A 68 6B 6A 68 6A 00 02 00 00 00 FF FF"
i checked the s.Length is returned incorrect size !
Why the result the entropy is not correct ?

Comment: Because `s.Length` is not the number of items in the set? `hexValuesSplit.Length` would be

Comment: thanks that's solve my problem